# A set a member of another set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can we say the following?

Given: $L_{1}$ and $L_{2}$ as finite sets. C as a finite set. $L_{1}$ $\in$ C and $L_{2}$ $\in$ C. Suppose that $x \in L_{1} \cap L_{2}$. Is $x \in C$?

I know that $x$ should be in $C$, but I'm not sure given the official definition of membership this $x \in C$ would be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason to expect that $x\in C$. Suppose that $L_1=\{0,1\}$, $L_2=\{1,2\}$, and $C=\{L_1,L_2\}$. Then $1\in L_1\cap L_2$, but $1\notin C$.